# Insert a variable into a variable name inside a function

Tags: php

I have a function;

```
function foo($foo)
{
     $new_foo_{$foo} = $_POST['$submitted_foo_{$foo}'];
}

foo(1);
```

It is failing because $foo is not being inserted into the variable.
I've looked for the proper syntax to accomplish this task but it has thus far eluded me.

Is this even possible?
My reasoning for this is I have multiple inputs that have names that are off by a single digit so making a function and calling it will save me from breaking DRY.

Alternative methods to accomplish this task would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: you could use an associative array to store the values..

Comment: Not a good thing to do but have you looked up variable variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_POST['submitted_foo_1'] = 'test';
function foo($foo)
{
     ${"new_foo_$foo"} = $_POST["submitted_foo_".$foo];
     echo $new_foo_1;

}

foo(1);

you can also create variable names similar to input names on fly:

//for example $_POST = array('name' => .., 'email' => ., 'submit' =>...)
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
  $$key = $val;
}
//now $name, $email, $submit available
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do so, but it is not a good way of achieving your goal.

If you want to use it inside the function you simply need a **global** keyword so the resulting variable has a global scope:

```
function foo($foo)
{
     global ${"new_foo_$foo"};
     ${"new_foo_$foo"} = $_POST["$submitted_foo_{$foo}"];
}

foo(1) 

echo $new_foo_1;
```